# Convert WP theme to Orchard

Tags: wordpress, orchardcms

Where can I find instructions or tools to convert a WordPress theme to Orchard ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WordPress is a php based CMS. Orchard is ASP.NET.

Short answer is: you're not going to find any sort of automated converter.

However, I'm going to hedge a bet that you're mainly interested in the look-and-feel of the WP theme in question, and you aren't really asking about porting functionality. Look at index.php and single.php in your WP theme to find the base HTML markup. Look at styles.css or any other main CSS files to find the base styles. Then use [Frooth](http://www.orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Szmyd.Frooth). It allows easy modification of layout and styles via GUI. If you know the basics of HTML and CSS it should be more or less a cut-and-paste job.

Good luck!

Comment: Good answer, but not good enough. I'm trying to jump ship to Orchard and I have a few wordpress sites under my belt. Yeah I can tinker and do a hand job for them, but in the world of automation a tool described in the question is exactly what Orchard needs for a paradigm shift to occur. Php or not, a console app could use IO to read the php files and automagically know how to re-write them for an orchard theme. This would need someone who is a kung-fu master in both worlds.

Comment: The asker is obviously a novice, and this is the easiest way that actually exists. You're spinning pure fantasy.